# How can I create some kind of alert for the user in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a form:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only">Username</label>
        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Desired Username">
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
</form>
```

Here is my app.js:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {

  var user = new Parse.User();
  user.set("username", req.body.username);
  user.set("password", req.body.password);
  user.set("email", req.body.email);

  user.signUp(null, {
    success: function(user) {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
      console.log(user);
      res.redirect('/#register');
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
      // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
      console.log(error.message);
      res.redirect('/#register');

    }
  });

});
```

Everything functionally works, I just want to know how I can show a message if the user has been successfully signed up or not. I would also like to know if this is a correct way of handling a form.

Comment: You should call `res.send` to send the success message to the front-end and handle the redirection from there.

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Handle the success status after signUp.

```
success: function(user) {
  // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
  res.redirect('/#register');
}
```

On successful signup you are redirecting to /#register page. You can show an alert when this page is loaded.

Comment: `alert` doesn't exist on server-side, it only exists in the browser.

Comment: but my function is on the server side. how can i still do an alert?

Answer (score 0):

**Front-end JS:**

Instead of submitting the form the usual way, we will use [jQuery-AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for this purpose:

---

Attach `jQuery` to your web page using the below `<script>` tag in your web page's `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Follow it up in the same `<head>` with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.form-inline').submit(function(event) {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", // the request type
    url: "/", // the URL where your form data will be sent
    data: $(this).serialize(), // the form data to be sent
    success: function(data) { // this function will be called when you do a res.send from the back-end

        alert(data); // although I would suggest you use a modal or some other solution to display your success message

        window.location.href = your_redirect_url; // this will redirect the user to your /#register url

    }
  });

  event.preventDefault(); // to prevent the form from being submitted the usual way

});

</script>
```

**NOTE:** This is just an example to help you get started.

---

**Back-end JS:**

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {

  ...

  user.signUp(null, {
    success: function(user) {

      res.send(your_success_message); // send your success message or status or result object using this method, it will call the success function of your ajax object on the front-end
    },
    error: function(user, error) {

      res.send(your_error_message); // similarly send the error message, or status, or object.
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible to do this without Ajax? Like can i do it with just simple node and html?

Comment: If you do not want to use Ajax, then you will need to revert back to [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) which is a native function in the browser's Javascript. But Ajax is much simpler to use.

Comment: But, if you want to display the alert message on the same page as the form, then using Ajax or XMLHttpRequest is the only way to do it as far as I know.

Comment: How do i add the jQuery-Ajax in my html?

Comment: do i still keep <button>?

Comment: Yes, of course. Otherwise you can't submit the form! :P